# phpbrew switch does not change PHP version

Tags: php

If I run "phpbrew switch 5.6.3" followed by "php -v", i get 5.9.3 (PHP System Version) as current PHP Version.

If I run phpbrew "use 5.6.3", i also get 5.6.3 with php -v.

Is there any solution for this problem? PHP version 5.6.3 is installed and built with phpbrew and working after using the use command.

I am using Elementary OS Freya (Ubuntu 14.04) with the latest phpbrew version.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting a red error line "You should not see this, if you see this, it means you didn't load the ~/.phpbrew/bashrc script, please check if bashrc is sourced in your shell.", then you need to run `source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc`.  It's also a good idea to run `echo "source $HOME/.phpbrew/bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc`, so that in the future this will be automatic.

Comment: was getting that same error  `You should not see this, if you see this, it means you didn't load the ~/.phpbrew/bashrc script, please check if bashrc is sourced in your shell.` Your answer  Saved my Day, ;-)